# Reformatting HTML table - Align and Resizing cells

Tags: html, html-table

1. Align the outer (formatting) table cells with content starting in the top left corner of the cells. Set the two columns to equal width.
2. Align the cells (in `<td>`) in the nested table (use tag to identify only the inner table) to be centered in the middle.

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <head>
           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
           <title>Jake's Schedule</title>
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Web4.css"/>
       </head>

       <body>
           <h1>Jacob Martin</h1>
           <h3>This table shows my Fall Semester of classes</h3>
           <table>
               <tr>
                   <td class="topcolums"><span class="bold">Hometown:<br/><br/></span> Pulaski, WI<br />I have lived there for 19 years</td>

                   <td class="topcolums"><span class="bold"><span class="underlined">Education:<br/><br/>
                   </span></span> Soon to have Associates for CS<br />UW Fox Valley 2015 for Associates<br/>BA at UW Stout</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td rowspan="2"><h2>My Favorites</h2><br/> 
                       <ol>
                           <li id="musicians"><h3>Musicians</h3>
                               <ul>
                                   <li class="disc">Limp Bizkit</li>
                                   <li class="square">Kid Rock</li>
                               </ul></li>
                           <li id="hobbies"><h3>Hobbies</h3>
                               <ul>
                                   <li class="disc">Running</li>
                                   <li class="square">Video Games</li>
                               </ul></li>
                           <li id="websites"><h3>Websites</h3>
                               <ul>
                                   <li class="disc"><a href="http://www.ign.com">IGN</a></li>
                                   <li class="square"><a href="http://n4g.com">N4G</a></li>
                                   <li class="circle"><a href="http://www.wwe.com/wwenetwork">WWE Network</a></li>
                               </ul></li>
                       </ol>
                   </td>
                   <td><table border="2">
               <tr>
                   <th> </th>
                   <th>Monday</th>
                   <th>Tuesday</th>
                   <th>Wednesday</th>
                   <th>Thursday</th>
                   <th>Friday</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <th>8:00-<br/>8:59</th>
                   <div align="center"><td>Ethics</td>
                   <td rowspan="2">Data Structors</td>
                   <td>Ethics</td>
                   <td rowspan="2">Data Structors</td>
                   <td>Ethics</td></div>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <th>9:00-<br/>9:59</th>
                   <div align="center"><td>study</td>
                   <td>study</td>
                   <td>study</td></div>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <th>10:00-<br/>10:59</th>
                   <div align="center"><td colspan="5">Calculas II</td></div>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <th>11:00-<br/>11:59</th>
                   <div align="center"><td colspan="5">study</td></div>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <th>12:00-<br/>12:59</th>
                   <div align="center"><td colspan="5">study</td></div>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <th>1:00-<br/>1:59</th>
                   <div align="center"><td colspan="5">study</td></div>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <th>2:00-<br/>2:59</th>
                   <div align="center"><td colspan="5">study</td></div>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <th>3:00-<br/>3:59</th>
                   <div align="center"><td>Linear Algebra</td>
                   <td>study</td>
                   <td>Linear Algebra</td>
                   <td>study</td>
                   <td>Linear Algebra</td></div>
               </tr>
           </table></td>
               </tr>

                   <tr><td colspan="2"><p>My goals goals for this Summer is to learn how to make webpages with HTML.<br/> I also want to learn more about Computer Programming in general.<br/> I have 4 classes and I want to be ready for my website job this fall.</p></td></tr>

           </table>

           <img id="image" src="../Web2/future.jpg" alt="The Future"style= width="400px" height="200px"/>

           <p>a&#178; + b&#178; = c&#178;</p>
           <p>&#189; &#62; &#188; &amp; 0&#176; C &#60; 33&#176; F</p>

           <p>
       <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer"><img
         src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10" alt="Valid XHTML 1.0 Transitional" height="31" width="88" /></a>
     </p>
       </body>
       </html>
   ```

Can I get an explanation of 1 and 2. How can i solve it? I am assuming in 1 that it meant to make the width equal which i did in CSS. If that's the case can someone explain 2.

Comment: (1) It seems to me that you've got two tables. The first one holds all of your text info on the left and the second table on the right. The timetable should take-up the same width as the personal info. (2) the td elements of the timetable should be center-aligned.

Comment: do you have any image for design he wants from you to do

Comment: Enhzflep answered it well. She put up images, but they were very creative and difficult to see what she needed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: ok, she should put it as an answer and you vote up for her answer, to let others know the answer of your question